# Coordinating dragmove to not exceed 30 FPS

Tags: javascript, animation, kineticjs

I have animation that happens on dragmove. 
However I don't want to waste cycles doing more calculations than I have to.
Essentially I want the dragmove events to only redraw at a reasonable animation rate.

In other words dragmove events come in as fast as they can however I only want to execute code as often as needed for smoothness for user.

So far the only solution I have come up with is to have a separate animation loop that does the redraw and ondragmove just sets the variables I need.  Is there a more elegant way of doing this?

Comment: What you have now, animation interval with updated coordinates in real time, might actually be perfect, though, depending on the rest of your project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think about it this way. The 30 FPS is your limitation. The events will go on their own time regardless your limitations.

So your idea is not that "un-elegant". I would say, it's the only way to go.

When ever you get a motion event, store it locally, if you already have it stored, override the old data(This is the ignoring part). From your 30 FPS loop, sample the motion event, if you got anything, than execute and destroy it.

This is about it. Pretty much your own words.